# UIActionSheet weird animation?

Tags: ios, debugging, animation, uiactionsheet

Currently I have a UIActionSheet in View B. I have the UIActionSheet launched in the ViewDidLoad. But the problem is that, the UIActionSheet has some weird animating that comes in from the top and from the side which is not supposed to happen. Anyway I think it is because I launch the UIActionSheet while ViewB is still being animated in from View A. So is there some certain delegate method that gets fired in the OS when the current view stops animating when your switching views?

Or is there any other way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `-viewDidAppear:` in view controller B, and present your action sheet there.